# Group_Id to call Venuegroups

Tags: foursquare

Where might I find this mythical Group_Id so I can call the venuegroups endpoint?  Does this mean there are going to be groups for chains? starbucks, mcdonalds, etc...

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venuegroups/venuegroups.html

Answer (score 0):

Group IDs are created by venue managers to create groups of venues they manage for the purpose of running Specials Campaigns.

Managers can get a list of their group IDs from the /venuegroups/list endpoint https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venuegroups/list.html